# Is it possible to omit escaping some html in <c:out value="${str}">?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I want make secure display (escaping html characters with c:out) but allow some links (`<img>` `<a href>` and youtube embedded). How can I do this? Is it possible achieve this with c:out?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`escapeXml`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html)

```
<c:out value="${test}" escapeXml="true" />
```

To prevent XSS attacks also look at [JSoup Cleaner](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer)

Comment: Which is the default behaviour, if you omit the `escapeXml` attribute

Comment: but how can I add img, a href and youtube embedded real html to this?

Comment: let's say I'm writing a blog system and in users posts I want allow only html tags to img, links to web pages and youtube.

Comment: then parse the input submitted and check if any other XSS things are coming strip out it you can use JSoup for this

Comment: thanks, JSoup Cleaner looks interesting (I used JSoup parser before and works great). I'll try this one and also maybe something with org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils with EscapeHtml method and avoid c:out.